# 'CommandDisabled' while running Skype Web SDK samples preview

Tags: skypedeveloper

I am able to chat using business accounts alright. However, when I try to add audio or video to these conv(ersation), like conv.audioService.start(), I get commandDisabled error.

I was not able to find satisfactory explanation of this when I did Google Search, hence the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio and Video conversations initially were available for Public Preview [product keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/apiproductkeys) only. Later they had updated the documentation and added audio/video to General Availability keys support. Indeed, take in account (state at Jun 12 2017), that while with the preview keys your app will try make an audio/video call in Chrome or Firefox, with the GA keys it will not (CommandDisabled) - they aren't supported browsers (only IE, Edge and Safari will do).

Comment: Hello Peter, Thank you very much for the information. can you provide me with the link that explains this as well? It will help me look this up next time on myself.

Comment: It is a page with Product Keys https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/apiproductkeys, everything else it's experimenting with the API. I don't have other references to official explanations.

Comment: I think with either keys video is not supported in Chrome/Firefox as these browsers stopped supporting plugins.